# undefined index on $_SESSION and all $_POST part

Tags: php, mysqli, registration

I want to make register form for my website. But I faced error and this is my code:

```
<?php

/* Registration process, inserts user info into the database 
and sends account confirmation email message
*/

// Set session variables to be used on profile.php page

$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $_POST['lastname'];


$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 // Escape all $_POST variables to protect against SQL injections
$first_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'],                     
PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
 $hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

  // Check if user with that email already exists
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$email'") or        
 die($mysqli->error());

// We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = 'User with this email already exists!';
header("location: error.php");

  }
 else { // Email doesn't already exist in a database, proceed...

// active is 0 by DEFAULT (no need to include it here)
$sql = "INSERT INTO login (first_name, last_name, email, password, hash)" 
        ."VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password',     '           
   $hash')";

// Add user to the database
if ( $mysqli->query($sql) ){

    $_SESSION['active'] = 0; //0 until user activates their account with    

  verify.php
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // So we know the user has logged in
    $_SESSION['message'] =

             "Confirmation link has been sent to $email, please verify
             your account by clicking on the link in the message!";

    // Send registration confirmation link (verify.php)
    $to      = $email;
    $subject = 'Account Verification ( clevertechie.com )';
    $message_body = '
    Hello '.$first_name.',

    Thank you for signing up!

    Please click this link to activate your account:

    http://localhost/login-system/verify.php?email='.$email.'&               
    hash='.$hash;  

    mail( $to, $subject, $message_body );

    header("location: profile.php"); 

     }


else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registration failed!';
    header("location: error.php");
    exit();
}

 }
```

The error state that:

```
Undefined index: firstname, lastname, email, password
```

at line set session variables and line for escape all $_POST variables to protect SQL injection. Anyone know how to fix this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `session_start()` at the start of your code, this needs to be called before you echo/output anything to the browser.

You'll also need to add `session_start` to your `error.php` to read from the session there.

> When session_start() is called or when a session auto starts, PHP will call the open and read session save handlers...
>
> The read callback will retrieve any existing session data (stored in a special serialized format) and will be unserialized and used to automatically populate the $_SESSION superglobal when the read callback returns the saved session data back to PHP session handling.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

```
If(isset($_POST['first_name']) &&     isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
 // Escape all $_POST variables to protect  against SQL injections
$first_name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = $mysqli- >escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
}
```

In PHP, a variable or array element which has never been set is different from one whose value is null; attempting to access such an unset value is a runtime error.

That's what you're running into: the array $_POST does not have any element at the index "username", so the interpreter aborts your program before it ever gets to the nullity test.